# Maven multi module local package not exists after compilation

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, module

I'd been working on project focused on personal finance management. The project is based on Spring Boot, and to the current moment was develop as single module project.

Recently I started to move the logic to separate maven modules, but have an issue that have been struggling for too much time right now.

I'm facing error during compilation one of my child modules:

**package pl.intelligent.finance.persistence.entity does not exist**
and **cannot find symbol**

during ex. mvn clean install/package

There are no errors in IDE. Dependencies are set to default level so should be available at compile (have tried other levels as well). Above package was compiled successfully before this exception.

I have read a bunch of other posts on StackOverflow and other sites and currently without any solution, so kindly please do not start with "possible duplicate" :)

I will not post code/config here because of max post length, so here is the full project on public repo (branch mm_structure):
https://github.com/PeterStuck/intelligent-finance-app

Any help will be appriciated!

BR,
Peter

Comment: how did you specify the dependencies between the modules in the module poms, how did you specify the modules in the master pom and for which pom did you start the build?

Comment: Adding to the @cyberbrain question , we can see multiple main classes in you multi module springboot project. Which is your main module where you should have all your dependencies of modules get repackaged ? Correct those and your project will run without any issues.

Comment: I tested it locally and I think that the spring-boot-maven-plugin is the thing that makes the troubles: if I disable it (comment out) everywhere (in the main pom and in the persistence-repositories pom), package works fine. 
The build message that made me think its causing the troubles was "spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.3:repackage (repackage) @ persistence-entity-interface Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive" - and the missing interfaces are all from that `persistend-entity-interface` module. Try to reconfigure that maven plugin properly to use it.

Comment: Hi @cyberbrain and @Rishal. I'm total begginer in spring multi module application, so sorry for inaccuracies. My main class for which I will start my app is `IntelligentFinanceApplication` placed in module `finance-main-system`. I added second for tests purpose to create Application Context inside unit tests. The application structure is not ended yet. I'm missing REST resource module to properly connect it to `finance-main-system` module, but I think this should not be the problem if I compile this modules one by one instead of `mvn clean install` from root directory, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Also @cyberbrain, could you kindly explain what you mean by `reconfigure that maven plugin properly to use it`? I commented out currently plugin configuration and on my side there are no changes when it comes to compilation errors :( Maybe I'm missing someting in Intellij IDE configuration?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot really provide help to configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin, I just found out that removing it from the two pom.xml files where it is contained, helps to perform `mvn clean package`. (If I had details on how to do it properly I would have written an answer instead of a comment ;-) ) From its [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) I saw that you have some configs for maven that are not necessary. I would try to skip the repackage-goal for your non-main-modules.